# Can't find mysql/mysql.h after upgrading to 5.6

Tags: mysql, c, makefile

Yesterday I upgraded mysql from 5.5 to 5.6 using the directions on [this page](https://rtcamp.com/tutorials/mysql/mysql-5-6-ubuntu-12-04/#comment-115809) it all went fine and mysql client connects and I didn't lose any data or anything bad like that.

Today I went to work on a C program of mine that uses the mysql libraries. My make failed because I didn't have the correct flags from `mysql_config --cflags` and `mysql_config --libs` which I've fixed. So now my make file has the flags defined like so:

```
mysqlflags = -I/opt/mysql/server-5.6/include  -fPIC -g -fabi-version=2 -fno-omit-frame- pointer -fno-strict-aliasing -DMY_PTHREAD_FASTMUTEX=1
mysqllibs  = -L/opt/mysql/server-5.6/lib -lmysqlclient -lpthread -lm -lrt -ldl
```

But when I compile I get the error:

```
In file included from ./headers/controllers/comments.h:12:0,
             from src/controllers/comments.c:1:
./headers/db.h:4:26: fatal error: mysql/mysql.h: No such file or directory
```

So I went ahead and checked out my include folder and sure enough there's no header:

```
ls /opt/mysql/server-5.6/include/mysql
client_authentication.h  innodb_priv.h      plugin_auth_common.h  plugin_ftparser.h.pp           service_my_plugin_log.h  service_thd_alloc.h
client_plugin.h                    plugin_auth.h         plugin.h                    service_my_snprintf.h    service_thd_wait.h
client_plugin.h.pp       plugin_audit.h     plugin_auth.h.pp       plugin_validate_password.h  service_mysql_string.h   service_thread_scheduler.h
get_password.h           plugin_audit.h.pp  plugin_ftparser.h     psi                         services.h               thread_pool_priv.h`
```

If I look one directory up, in the include folder itself I have

```
 ls /opt/mysql/server-5.6/include/
big_endian.h                 keycache.h       my_byteorder.h  my_global.h   mysql_com_server.h  mysql_version.h    plugin_validate_password.h  typelib.h
byte_order_generic.h         little_endian.h  my_compiler.h   my_list.h     mysqld_ername.h     my_sys.h           sql_common.h
byte_order_generic_x86_64.h  m_ctype.h        my_config.h     my_net.h      mysqld_error.h      my_xml.h           sql_state.h
byte_order_generic_x86.h     m_string.h       my_dbug.h       my_pthread.h  mysql_embed.h       plugin_audit.h     sslopt-case.h
decimal.h                    my_alloc.h       my_dir.h        mysql         mysql.h             plugin_ftparser.h  sslopt-longopts.h
errmsg.h                     my_attribute.h   my_getopt.h     mysql_com.h   mysql_time.h        plugin.h           sslopt-vars.h
```

Seeing the mysql.h there made me say, oh ok it's just in the wrong place. I tried doing an

`#include <mysql.h>` to see if it would pick it up, no dice. I tried copying the mysql.h file to the mysql/ folder but that didn't do anything either and when I did `locate mysql.h` it only showed the one in the include folder as well.

Can anyone point me towards some documentation for a change for developing for mysql 5.6 versus 5.5? The [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/c-api-building-clients.html) isn't saying anything I haven't already done

*Edit:* 
This the relevant portion of the makefile output

```
cc -I/opt/mysql/server-5.6/include/mysql  -fPIC -g -fabi-version=2 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-strict-aliasing -DMY_PTHREAD_FASTMUTEX=1 -I./headers -std=gnu99 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Werror -g -c src/database/db.c -o obj/db.o     
In file included from src/database/db.c:1:0:
./headers/db.h:4:26: fatal error: mysql/mysql.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

Also I reran the `mysql --cflags` to make sure and I wrote it down wrong above, the actual output is

`-I/opt/mysql/server-5.6/include/mysql  -fPIC -g -fabi-version=2 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-strict-aliasing -DMY_PTHREAD_FASTMUTEX=1`

and that's what I'm using to compile and still getting the error

Comment: Are you sure that you pass all the flags to the compiler?

Comment: would it help if I posted the output of my makefile to verify that?

Comment: The full makefile is here: https://github.com/EJEHardenberg/green-serv/blob/master/Makefile  and the only difference between that one and my local are the `mysqlflags` and `mysqllib` variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have added

```
/opt/mysql/server-5.6/include/mysql
```

as an include path, and then, in your header file, you `#include <mysql/mysql.h>`. This is relative to the include path, so (apart from the default include path), the compiler is looking for a file with the path

```
/opt/mysql/server-5.6/include/mysql/mysql/mysql.h
```

which it won't find. You should either change your code to just `#include <mysql.h>` or change the include path you pass to the compiler to `/opt/mysql/server-5.6/include`.

### Edit:

Sorry, I've realized just now that the `mysql.h` ist located at `/opt/mysql/server-5.6/include/mysql.h`, not `/opt/mysql/server-5.6/include/mysql/mysql.h`.
You have to do both: add `/opt/mysql/server-5.6/include` as an include path **and** change your code to `#include <mysql.h>`.

Comment: I've tried both of those things, both doing just `#include <mysql.h>` and changing the path to just have `/include` at the end, same problem, it can't find mysql.h

Comment: Sorry, I had that mixed up. Could you do _both_, please? I've also edited the answer.

Comment: Cool. This fixes it, although it forces me to include $(mysqlflags) on all my cc calls for _anything_ that includes db.h which is strange to me since I didn't need to do that before.
Thanks though!

Comment: I suppose that before, you had the MySQL header files located somewhere in your default include path. mysql.h would be found automatically. But now, since it is in a different location, you have to tell the compiler where to find it.

Comment: When I installed everything with apt-get before (for 5.5), I'm pretty sure it installed it into /usr/include as oppose to being in the /opt directory that it is now. I could move things around, but I think I'm good for now. It's too easy to foobar the way mysql and other programs interact sometimes. Thanks for all your help though!